# SQL compare multiple rows or partitions to find matches

Tags: sql, db2

The database I'm working on is DB2 and I have a problem similar to the following scenario:

```
Table Structure
-------------------------------
| Teacher Seating Arrangement |
-------------------------------
| PK | seat_argmt_id          |
|    | teacher_id             |
-------------------------------

-----------------------------
| Seating Arrangement       |
-----------------------------
|PK FK | seat_argmt_id      |
|PK    | Row_num            |
|PK    | seat_num           |
|PK    | child_name         |
-----------------------------

Table Data
------------------------------
| Teacher Seating Arrangement|
------------------------------
| seat_argmt_id | teacher_id |
|         1     |     1      |
|         2     |     1      |
|         3     |     1      |
|         4     |     1      |
|         5     |     2      |
------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------
| Seating Arrangement                             |
---------------------------------------------------
| seat_argmt_id | row_num | seat_num | child_name |
|        1      |    1    |    1     |     Abe    |
|        1      |    1    |    2     |     Bob    |
|        1      |    1    |    3     |     Cat    |
|               |         |          |            |
|        2      |    1    |    1     |     Abe    |
|        2      |    1    |    2     |     Bob    |
|        2      |    1    |    3     |     Cat    |
|               |         |          |            |
|        3      |    1    |    1     |     Abe    |
|        3      |    1    |    2     |     Cat    |
|        3      |    1    |    3     |     Bob    |
|               |         |          |            |
|        4      |    1    |    1     |     Abe    |
|        4      |    1    |    2     |     Bob    |
|        4      |    1    |    3     |     Cat    |
|        4      |    2    |    2     |     Dan    |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I want to see where there are duplicate seating arrangements for a teacher. And by duplicates I mean where the `row_num`, `seat_num`, and `child_name` are the same among different `seat_argmt_id` for one `teacher_id`. So with the data provided above, only seat id 1 and 2 are what I would want to pull back, as they are duplicates on everything but the `seat id`. If all the children on the 2nd table are exact (sans the primary & foreign key, which is `seat_argmt_id` in this case), I want to see that.

My initial thought was to do a `count(*) group by row#, seat#, and child`. Everything with a count of > 1 would mean it's a dupe and = 1 would mean it's unique. That logic only works if you are comparing single rows though. I need to compare multiple rows. I cannot figure out a way to do it via SQL. The solution I have involves going outside of SQL and works (probably). I'm just wondering if there is a way to do it in DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select d.teacher_id, sa.row_num, sa.seat_num, sa.child_name
from seatingarrangement sa join
     data d
     on sa.seat_argmt_id = d.seat_argmt_id
group by d.teacher_id, sa.row_num, sa.seat_num, sa.child_name
having count(*) > 1;
```

EDIT:

If you want to find two arrangements that are the same:

```
select sa1.seat_argmt_id, sa2.seat_argmt_id
from seatingarrangement sa1 join
     seatingarrangement sa2
     on sa1.seat_argmt_id < sa2.seat_argmt_id and
        sa1.row_num = sa2.row_num and
        sa1.seat_num = sa2.seat_num and
        sa1.child_name = sa2.child_name
group by sa1.seat_argmt_id, sa2.seat_argmt_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from seatingarrangement sa where sa.seat_argmt_id = sa1.seat_argmt_id) and
       count(*) = (select count(*) from seatingarrangement sa where sa.seat_argmt_id = sa2.seat_argmt_id);
```

This finds the matches between two arrangements and then verifies that the counts are correct.

Comment: This was similar to what I first thought would be the solution, but it is incorrect. You are comparing row by row, but I need to compare multiple rows by multiple rows. Using the data above, Abe sits in the same seat for all the arrangements, but not all the arrangements are the same. I need it where every child is sitting in the exact same seat. Bob sits in Seat 2 in the first arrangement, but in seat 3 on the third arrangement, so those two would not be considered the same.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I tried it in SQLFiddle and it worked. Played around with it and did some more research on SQL to figure out exactly how it works. I remember coming across something similar to this when searching for something else a couple years back. So this seems to be a known algorithm. Do you happen to know if there is a name for this?

Comment: Since the problem states that the goal is to find "duplicate seating arrangements for a teacher", don't you want to add teacher to the join conditions?

Comment: I know how to do that, it was the duplicate seating arrangement part I was stuck on. Thanks though!